# Convert to number of rows based on record value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have a scenario where i am currently stucked in

table abc having amount,fromdate,todate,numberofquarters(calculated from todate fromdate)

Example:

```
amount  fromdate    todate      numberofquarters

140    01/01/2011   06/01/2014   14
```

I have to make the above table in pro rata basis of quarter
i.e 14 records as

```
amount  fromdate    todate      
10     01/01/2011   03/31/2011   
10     01/04/2011   06/30/2011   
10     01/07/2011   09/31/2011   
10     01/10/2011   12/31/2011  
10     01/01/2012   03/31/2012   
10     01/04/2012   06/30/2012   
10     01/07/2012   09/31/2012   
10     01/10/2012   12/31/2012  
10     01/01/2013   03/31/2013   
...and so on
```

Please suggest me any approach through which i can achieve the result without using cursors.

Comment: Can we get a little clarity on the desired output? I'm assuming amount is the sum, fromdate is the minimum fromdate and todate is the maximum todate. How often do you want to run this query? Also, 9/31 isn't a date...

Comment: Amount is something have to split into number of quarters In the above example there are 14 quarters calculated from todate and fromdate. So the amount should be calculated as amount/numberofquarters.Yes this will run quartely but date can be anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do things like this either by having a permanent date or numbers table (one row per date or number), or construct it dynamically, with something like this:

```
;WITH lv0 AS (SELECT 0 g UNION ALL SELECT 0)
    ,lv1 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv0 a CROSS JOIN lv0 b) -- 4
    ,lv2 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv1 a CROSS JOIN lv1 b) -- 16
    ,lv3 AS (SELECT 0 g FROM lv2 a CROSS JOIN lv2 b) -- 256
    ,Tally (n) AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM lv3)
SELECT 
  abc.amount / numberofquarters, 
  dateadd(month, (n-1)*3, abc.fromdate) as fromdate,
  dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(month, n*3, abc.fromdate)) as todate
FROM 
  Tally T 
  join abc on abc.numberofquarters >= T.N
Order by fromdate
```

That will create a table with 256 rows, if you need more quarters, then just add one more similar join into the CTE. That is then joined with abc so that the number is used for adding months to the start date.

Example in [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/591d5/1)

Comment: When i run this in sql server it is saying as "Common table expression defined but not used".I am not getting why is this issue arising?

Comment: @user2941762 Check that you're referring all the virtual tables (lv0 .. lv3 and Tally)  in the CTE (with) part in either select in the CTE or in the final select.

Comment: Thanks James.I am using exactly the same query as above but instead of abc table I am using #temp table.Does Temp table causing this error?

Comment: @user2941762 No, the error says that you're not referring the CTE. It will work with normal and temp. tables

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the desired output of: 
  amount = sum of amount column, 
  fromdate = minimum of the fomdate column, 
  todate = minimum of the todate column
  quarters don't span over years.

```
SELECT
    amount,
    fromdate,
    todate,
    COUNT(DISTINCT CASE 
       WHEN DATEPART(DAY, fromdate) > DATEPART(DAY, todate)
       THEN DATEDIFF(MONTH, fromdate, todate) - 1
       ELSE DATEDIFF(MONTH, fromdate, todate)
    END % 3 + YEAR(fromdate)) quarters
FROM (
    SELECT 
      SUM(amount) amount,
      MIN(fromdate) fromdate, 
      MAX(todate) todate
      FROM abc
 ) subq
```

should give you the results you want

Comment: Thanks dear.But this is exactly the opposite of what i want.